# SharePoint timer service for backup/restore

Tags: 2010, permissions, configuration, backup, restore

for performing backups, SharePoint timer service should have read/write permission. How i check if SharePoint timer service have read/write permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the "SharePoint farm account" that runs the OWSTimer (timer job service) in SharePoint.
 You can check which account is currently actually running the timer job service by going to Services -> SharePoint 2010 Timer and Properties -> Log on

[image]

Comment: Give Allow access to everything for your SharePoint Timer service account to the folder you will place your backup to. The reason we’re using the farm account is because that’s normally what your SharePoint Timer Service is running as.  If it’s going to be running/is running as another account, setup the above permissions for that account instead.

Comment: Ok! Its log on as SPDEV\svcFarm account. But for the person performing backup, it should be member of Farm administrator's Group. Now how i check if farm administrator's Group running timer job service ?

Comment: It depends what you plan to backup. For example, if you want to back up the service application, web application, content database, farm  etc. , you have to grant the person performing the backup with `Add-SPShellAdmin` rights + some other permissions on SQL server. You can see the details of each backup type on technet http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748624(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: One more thing, you don't need add person performing the backup as a Farm administrator but instead give additional rights using `Add-SPShellAdmin`